# Variable PHP Variables

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I am new to the concept of variable variables and don't think I fully understand it.

What I am trying to do is create a for loop that will populate an array based on a variable number of variables.

I am trying to replace: (manually hard coded)

```
$numCorrectArray = array(1=>$q01TotalCorrect, 2=>$q02TotalCorrect, 3=>$q03TotalCorrect, 4=>$q04TotalCorrect, 5=>$q05TotalCorrect, 6=>$q06TotalCorrect, 7=>$q07TotalCorrect, 8=>$q08TotalCorrect, 9=>$q09TotalCorrect, 10=>$q10TotalCorrect, 11=>$q11TotalCorrect, 12=>$q12TotalCorrect, 13=>$q13TotalCorrect, 14=>$q14TotalCorrect, 15=>$q15TotalCorrect, 16=>$q16TotalCorrect, 17=>$q17TotalCorrect, 18=>$q18TotalCorrect, 19=>$q19TotalCorrect, 20=>$q20TotalCorrect, 21=>$q21TotalCorrect, 22=>$q22TotalCorrect, 23=>$q23TotalCorrect, 24=>$q24TotalCorrect, 25=>$q25TotalCorrect, 26=>$q26TotalCorrect, 27=>$q27TotalCorrect, 28=>$q28TotalCorrect, 29=>$q29TotalCorrect);
```

With: (dynamic)

```
$numCorrectArray = array();

for($i=1; $i <= $stats->numberOfQuestions; $i++) {

    if($i < 10) {
        $questionNumber = "0" . $i; 
    } else {
        $questionNumber = $i;               
    }
    $varName = "q" . $questionNumber . "TotalCorrect";

array_push($numCorrectArray, $$varName);
}
```

How would I accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have so curious named variables?

Comment: $i seems to be used uninitialized

Comment: "*I am new to the **concept of variable variables***"?

Comment: @Lion: Yes, variable variables exist.

Comment: I need to store an array of values for how many times a given question is answered correctly for later uses such as sorting, splicing, calculations, etc.

Comment: array key 01,02 etc seems pointless

Comment: Your code works http://ideone.com/jgOC2, but in the original code the array starts at index 1

Comment: @JohnCharles117 I think you've already accomplished what you wanted. A variable variable is just a reference to a variable by its name. For example, if you have $apple = 5; you can reference to it by its name. $varName = "apple"; $$varName becomes interpreted as $apple (since $varName = "apple") and therefore in this instance $$varName has the value integer 5. How you handled $$varName in your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The below method i think is easier to understand because is similar to normal PHP code. [Here you can learn more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$numCorrectArray = array();

$prefix = 'q';
$sufix  = 'TotalCorrect';

for($i=1; $i <= 30; $i++) {

    if($i < 10) {
        $questionNumber = "0" . $i; 
    } else {
        $questionNumber = $i;               
    }

    ${$prefix . $questionNumber . $sufix} = $i;

    $numCorrectArray[$i] = ${$prefix . $questionNumber . $sufix};

}
```